# How to add all type dependencies in TS project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I don't really want to add types manually for each dependency I installed. Maybe there is a way to install all types at once for a specific project with dependencies list in package.json (using some binary for example). I am new to TS env., thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use TypeScript with autocomplete, you need to get the types from somewhere.
Some `npm` packages come with integrated TypeScript declarations or better yet, hold their complete code base with TypeScript.

I've never heard of a possibility of downloading all existing types locally, but in a specific project you can install the relevant types, by searching/adding types using the `@types` prefix like so:

```
npm i --save uuid
npm i --save-dev @types/node @types/uuid
```

This will install the typings only in dev environment, and put them in a special folder under `node_modules/@types`

Comment: What do you mean by `downloading all existing types locally`? I mean for a specific project of course.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to install types automatically since version may change, inconsistencies may occur and those are packages you add to your project's `package.json`. Having said that, you have a package called `types-installer` in the npm store, which may help achieve what you want. But again, IMO this is not a good idea, better to add each dependency manually.

Answer (score 0):

[DefinatalyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/) provides you with types ready, typings from most popular packages are included.

You can use their [search engine](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/) to see if the packages are available.

Comment: Thanks but I ask for a way to not doing this.